# Field of algebraic numbers over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $F$ be the field of algebraic numbers over $\mathbb{Q}$. I do remember that this means $F$ is a field extension of rationals over $\mathbb{Q}$.

How do I show that no field extension of $F$ is algebraic? I am stuck on this and I would like a hint or two.

Comment: The field of *all* algebraic numbers definitely isn't a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$...

Comment: Also, what is $E$?

Comment: If $F$ is the field of all algebraic numbers, then $F$ is algebraically closed, so it has no proper algebraic extensions. So $E$ can be any proper extension of $F$.

Comment: The field of all algebraics is not a finite extension of the rationals. Note that an infinite extension can still be algebraic.

Answer (score 2):

A field extension $E/F$ is algebraic if for every $\alpha \in E$, the field extension $F(\alpha)/F$ is finite. Equivalently, $\alpha$ is the root of some polynomial in $F[x]$. This says nothing about whether $E/F$ is finite or infinite. Indeed, both possibilities can occur.

As mentioned in the comments above, when $F$ is the set of all elements that are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, $F/\mathbb{Q}$ is not a finite extension. Can you see why?

Keeping with $F$ the field of algebraic numbers over $\mathbb{Q}$, suppose $E/F$ is a nontrivial field extension. In other words, $F \subset E$ and $F \neq E$. Then there exists an $\alpha \in E \setminus F$. Can $\alpha$ be algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$? Can $\alpha$ be algebraic over $F$?

Comment: I think $\alpha$ can be algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$. I also think it can be algebraic over $F$, but I'm not 100% confident. I know obviously $\alpha$ is not going to be algebraic over $E$, if $E$ is not finite-dimensional.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, then wouldn't $\alpha$ be an element of the field of all algebraic numbers over $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. $F$?

Comment: Yes, $\alpha$ would be an element of $F$.

Comment: To say $\alpha \in E$ is not algebraic over $E$ is to say that the field extension $E(\alpha)/E$ is infinite. But $E(\alpha) = E$, the field extension is of degree 1.

Comment: If I could backtrack a bit: We know that $\alpha \in E$ because $\alpha \in F$, and $F \subset E$ (since $E/F$ is an field extension of $F$). Am I right on this?

Comment: I think you are missing the fact that we started by saying: "There exists an $\alpha \in E \setminus F$". In other words, we began by assuming that $\alpha$ was *not* in $F$.

Comment: So we suppose $\alpha \not\in F$ (rather, $\alpha \in E \setminus F$), based on the fact that $F \subset E$ (since $E$ is a field extension of $F$. Btw, is the term "nontrivial", in nontrivial field extension, important here?). If $\alpha \in E \setminus F$ is not algebraic over $E$, then it means the field extension of $E \setminus F$ is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: Am I left to show that $\alpha$ is not algebraic in $E \setminus F$?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13914/discussion-between-rghthndsd-and-glacier)

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I unaccepted your answer. My class presented a far different solution, in particular regarding use of the minimal polynimal $x^n-2=0$.

Comment: Feel free to post it. The question should certainly get *an* answer.